# what's the fanws cookie?

Tags: cookies, fantom, afbedsheet

I wrote a simple site using BedSheet to test adding cookies. When I ran the code and inspected the cookies using firebug, I found a extra cookie I didn't add named `fanws` (with value `06e3d816-7626-7b00-205a-0013e8a56e9d-dbc9c6c8fa03cfa4`).

Here is my code:

```java
class Site
{
    @Inject HttpCookies? cookie

    @Contribute { serviceType=Routes# }
    static Void contributeRoutes(Configuration Conf)
    {
        Conf.add(Route(`/index.html`, Site#index))
    }

    Text index()
    {
        cookie.add(Cookie("foo", "123"))
        return Text.fromHtml("<h1> Hello </h1>")
    }
}
```

What is this cookie? What is it used for? Where did this value come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fanws` stands for `Fanton Web Session` and is added by the `wisp` web server to manage sessions. The value is just a UUID that uniquely identifies the session.

You can read more in the `web` pod's documentation on [Web Sessions](http://www.fantom.org/doc/web/index#sessions).